# Calculate average of a column when same Name in another column

Tags: awk

I have a table with next columns:

```
Probe Name Sec_Name Number
A_1 One Bla 2
A_2 One Bla 5
A_3 One Bla 2
B_1 Two bli 1
B_2 Third 6
```

I want to check if the cells in second colum are repeated, and if they are, print a fifth column with the average of their numbers in fourth colum. 
Desired output:

```
Probe Name Sec_Name Number Average
A_1 One Bla 2
A_2 One Bla 5
A_3 One Bla 2 3
B_1 Two bli 1
B_2 Third 6
```

The table is separated by tab. I have tried something like this but... I want to have in the output, the same columns than in the input file.

```
awk '
{
    lines[$2]++;     
    totals[$2] += $4; 
}
END {

    for (i in lines) {
        print i, lines[i], totals[i] totals[i]/lines[i];;
    }
}
' file.txt
```

I hope it is more or less clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop twice through the file:

```
 awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]+=$4; b[$2]++; next}
     {printf "%s %s\n", $0, (b[$2]>1?a[$2]/b[$2]:"")}' file file
```

#### Explanation

- `FNR==NR {a[$2]+=$4; b[$2]++; next}` in the first loop, count the accumulated value of 2nd column (array `a[]` - your `totals[]`). Also, count how many times it has appeared (array `b[]` - your `lines[]`).
- `{printf "%s %s\n", $0, (b[$2]>1?a[$2]/b[$2]:"")}` in the second loop, print the line together with the results. Just print the average if the counter `b[]` is bigger than one for this 2nd column.

#### Test

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]+=$4; b[$2]++; next} {printf "%s %s\n", $0, (b[$2]>1?a[$2]/b[$2]:"")}' file file
Probe Name Sec_Name Number 
A_1 One Bla 2 3
A_2 One Bla 5 3
A_3 One Bla 2 3
B_1 Two bli 1 
B_2 Third 6
```

### Update

As per [Kent's great recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832303/calculate-average-of-a-column-when-same-name-in-another-column/23832396?noredirect=1#comment36669937_23832396), you can print the average value just last time 2nd column appears by using:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]+=$4; b[$2]++; c[$2]=FNR; next}
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
     {printf "%s %s\n", $0, (b[$2]>1&&c[$2]==FNR?a[$2]/b[$2]:"")}' file file
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It catches in the array `c[]` the line number of last time 2nd field appears. Then the printing condition also checks it, so that it just prints the average if it is last time 2nd column appears.

#### Test

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]+=$4; b[$2]++; c[$2]=FNR; next} {printf "%s %s\n", $0, (b[$2]>1&&c[$2]==FNR?a[$2]/b[$2]:"")}' a a
Probe Name Sec_Name Number 
A_1 One Bla 2 
A_2 One Bla 5 
A_3 One Bla 2 3
B_1 Two bli 1 
B_2 Third 6
```

Comment: +1, and to get the exact same output as OP desired: `awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]+=$4; b[$2]++; c[$2]=FNR;next}
     {printf "%s %s\n", $0, (b[$2]>1&&c[$2]==FNR?a[$2]/b[$2]:"")}' f f`

Comment: Yeah! Nice, nice one. Updated reflecting your suggestion. Thanks @Kent :)

Comment: Just perfect. Thanks also for the clear explanation.

Comment: {printf "%s\t%s\n", $0, (b[$2]>1?a[$2]/b[$2]:"") , just to have the fifth column separated with a tab instead of whitespace :)